# Solr SpellChecker | Collation is always null

Tags: solrnet

I am trying to implement spellCheck in solr. From the solr iterface i am able to see the collation but by using solr net **collation is always null**. The solrconfig and schema files which i am using are attached.

```
Here is the request handler and search component congiguation:

  <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" >
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_spell</str>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">textspell</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
      <!--<float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>-->
    </lst>
    <!-- a spellchecker that can break or combine words.  See "/spell" handler below for usage -->    
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="field">textspell</str>
      <str name="combineWords">true</str>
      <str name="breakWords">true</str>
      <int name="maxChanges">10</int>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>

 <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
         will be overridden by parameters in the request
      -->
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">spellcheck</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <!--<str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>-->
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">1</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxcollationtries">3</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationEvaluations">3</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateextendedresults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collatemaxcollectdocs">10</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

[solr net][1]


[solr interface][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj4vE.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLL8w.png
```